# Почему servlet отдает 404 ошибку?

Tags: java, servlet

Привет всем, не могли бы помочь решить проблему, давно мучаюсь. Я тут напишу код всего и вся

index.jsp

```
<!-- пример # 3 :  стартовая страница : index.jsp-->
<%@ page language="java" contentType=
"text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<html><body>
<FORM action="testform" method=POST>
<H3>Название проекта:
<INPUT type="text" name="Имя проекта" value="-задать-">
Технологии:
<TABLE BORDER=5> <tr>
<td>JSPX</td><td><INPUT type="radio" 
        name="Технология"
        value="JSP в формате XML"></td>
<td>JSTL</td><td><INPUT type="radio"
name="Технология"
        value="Библиотека тегов JSTL"></td>
        </tr></TABLE>
Язык программирования:
<TABLE BORDER=5> <tr>
 <td>Java 6<INPUT type="radio"
        name="Язык" 
        value="Java SE 6"></td>
<td>Java 5<INPUT type="radio"
        name="Язык"
        value="Java 1.5.0" checked></td>
</tr></TABLE></H3>
      <INPUT type="submit" value="Принять"> <BR>
</FORM>
</body></html>
```

RequestOutput.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class RequestOutput {
    public static void generate(HttpServletResponse resp,
 HttpServletRequest req) {
        try {
            String name, value;
resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

    out.print("<HTML><HEAD>");
    out.print("<TITLE>Результат</TITLE>");
    out.print("</HEAD><BODY>");
    out.print("<TABLE BORDER=3>");
    Enumeration names = req.getParameterNames();
        while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
            name = (String) names.nextElement();
            value = req.getParameterValues(name)[0];    /*
name = new String(name.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "utf-8");
value = new String(value.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "utf-8");
     */
            out.print("<TR>");
            out.print("<TD>" + name + "</TD>");
            out.print("<TD>" + value + "</TD>");
            out.print("</TR>");
            }
            out.print("</TABLE></BODY></HTML>");
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

web.xml (я его из ROOT обычно копирую, а потом вставляю свои данные)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   version="2.5">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RequestOutput</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>RequestOutput</servlet-class>
</servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RequestOutput</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/testform</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Все директории создал, все поместил куда надо, но отдает 404 ошибку, примерно такого вида. Если видите ошибки, вы скажите, пожалуйста, буду только рад.

ошибка

> `HTTP Status 404 - Servlet RequestOutput is not available`

И полный код ошибки

> type Status report
>
> message Servlet RequestOutput is not available
>
> description The requested resource (Servlet RequestOutput is not available) is not available.

Исправленный код RequestOutput.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class RequestOutput extends HttpServlet {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected final void doPost(final HttpServletRequest req,  final HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            String name, value;

resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

    out.print("<HTML><HEAD>");
    out.print("<TITLE>Результат</TITLE>");
    out.print("</HEAD><BODY>");
    out.print("<TABLE BORDER=3>");
    Enumeration names = req.getParameterNames(); 
    while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
        name = (String) names.nextElement();
        value = req.getParameterValues(name)[0]; 
    /*
name = new String(name.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "utf-8");
value = new String(value.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "utf-8");
     */
            out.print("<TR>");
            out.print("<TD>" + name + "</TD>");
            out.print("<TD>" + value + "</TD>");
            out.print("</TR>");
            }
            out.print("</TABLE></BODY></HTML>");
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Запускаю на windows 7,apache tomcat 6.0.35

Comment: дописал в ответ комментарии [Updated-2]

Comment: А больше ошибок нет?

Comment: ну на глаз я больше ничего не вижу, но если tomcat что-то выплевывает - то ему, конечно, лучше знать :)

Comment: Все ту же ошибку показывает

Comment: А сейчас стал белую страницу отдавать

Comment: хм, странно, скопировал твой код - все работает, с кодировкой конечно беда, но сервлет страницу отдает

Comment: у меня уже даже идеи закончились, посижу еще подумаю, попробуй заново создать новый проект - как кот себя поведет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

хм... а где

```
public class RequestOutput extends HttpServlet { }
```

?

и переопределите в нем метод.. или `doPost` или `service` и скопируйте туда код.

**[Updated]**

Как переопределить метод:

```
public class RequestOutput extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected final void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     // сюда скопируйте код из Вашего generate(...) метода
}
```

**[Updated-2]**

В целом похоже на правду, за исключением вот этого:

```
ServletRequest req1 = null;
Enumeration names = req1.getParameterNames();
```

Во-первых, это сразу выбросит `NullPointerException`, потому что req1 - null и Вы к нему пытаетесь обращаться.

Во вторых, у вас есть параметр `final HttpServletRequest req` - вот его и используйте:

```
Enumeration names = req.getParameterNames(); // req, а не req1
    while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
        name = (String) names.nextElement();
        value = req.getParameterValues(name)[0]; // req, а не req1
// ...
```

**[Updated-3]**

В логах исключения

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
    FormRequest (wrong name: chapt18/FormRequest)

java.lang.ClassCastException:
    chapt18.FormRequest cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
```

что это за класс такой `chapt18.FormRequest` ?
Откуда он взялся ?

**[Updated-4]**

А случайно в web.xml ничего лишнего не осталось ? Контейнер пытается загрузить этот класс. Значит где-то он "застрял", или какое-то упоминание о нем.

**[Updated-5]**

Данная ошибка говорит о том, что скомпилены исходники с помощью java 7, а запускаются на java 6, и виртуальная машина более старой версии конечно не понимает новую версию. Перекомпиль проект под java 6. И все должно быть норм.

**[Updated-6]**

Может быть и эклипс что-то создал, в любом случае, у тебя класс называется

```
public class servlet extends HttpServlet { }
```

а в `web.xml` почему-то указано:

```
<servlet-class>otvetform</servlet-class>
```

а должно быть (если я правильно все понимаю)

```
<servlet-class>servlet</servlet-class>
```

Comment: Вот с переопределением метода можете помочь,буду очень благодарен

Comment: Дописал пример в ответ

Comment: У меня в коде 
>resp 
подчеркивает

Comment: В сигнатуре метода (в моем примере), написано `HttpServletResponse response`, значит замените название на `resp` -> `final HttpServletResponse resp`

Comment: Удалить строку - `ServletRequest req1 = null`, и везде req1 заменить на req.

Comment: Запускаю все на:

    Server version: Apache Tomcat/6.0.26
    OS Name:        Windows 7
    Architecture:   x86
    JVM Version:    1.6.0_29-b11

Comment: А папки какие создали(WEB-INF там),и что не так с кодировкой,что изменить?

Comment: у меня еще стоит jdk1.7.0_06

Answer (score 0):

[[@masterMind](/users/8275/mastermind)](/users/8275/mastermind) Гигантское вам спасибо.Знаете в чем была ошибка?

```
 writer.print("<html>");
        writer.print("<head>");
        writer.print("<title>HelloWorld</title>");
        writer.print("<body>");
                writer.print(myName + ", Hello");
                writer.print("</body>");
```

А где закрывающий тег html)))

```
writer.print("<html>");
        writer.print("<head>");
        writer.print("<title>HelloWorld</title>");
        writer.print("<body>");
        writer.print(myName + ", Hello");
        writer.print("</body>");
        writer.print("</html>");//Вот из-за чего я мучался))
```

Comment: Может из-за кодировки?Кстати,у вас tomcat с автоматической установкой?

Comment: и jdk какой у вас версии стоит?

Comment: у меня стоит ждк - 1.6.0_29
Чтобы поправить кодировку, можно дописать в начале метода

    req.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

Comment: структура папок такая

    ROOT
    |
    +--- WEB-INF
    |    |
    |    +--- classes
    |    |    |
    |    |    + RequestOutput.class
    |    |
    |    + web.xml
    |
    + index.jsp

Comment: У меня структура такая же,может  с путями не так.У меня так :

>CATALINA_HOME C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.35
>CLASSPATH C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\lib
>JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06
>PATH C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin

Comment: Как собираешь, как запускаешь ?

Comment: Просто ставлю эти пути,и запускаю startup.bat,дальше ввожу

http://localhost:8080/FirstProject3/ 
ввожу и белый экран

Comment: хм, и в этой папке - FirstProject3, лежит структура, указанная выше? Что кот в логи пишет ?